# display the check mark check / uncheck checkbox jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to fill a text box with the system date using jquery.  the user will check and uncheck a checkbox to fill / unfill the txtbox with the date.  This works correctly yet the checkbox does not visually check or uncheck while it performs these actions.  how can i make the checkbox check and unckeck as the user clicks it?   Here is the code:

EDIT:  this is a asp.net checkbox I am using

```
 $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishFillCHK').toggle(function () {
            var myDate = new Date();
            var prettyDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + myDate.getDate() + '.' +
    myDate.getFullYear();
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishDateSrvcTXT').val(prettyDate);
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishFillCHK').attr('checked', true)
        }, function () {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishDateSrvcTXT').val('');
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishFillCHK').attr('checked', false);
        });
```

Comment: Im guessing your not using an actual input type="checkbox" element or?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML to go with this?

Comment: this issue was resolved by the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show/hide an element.  Use [click](http://api.jquery.com/click) to provide a handler for the click event, then check to see what the user did:

```
 $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishFillCHK').click(function () {
     if(this.checked) {
         var myDate = new Date();
         var prettyDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + myDate.getDate() + '.' +
myDate.getFullYear();
         $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishDateSrvcTXT').val(prettyDate);
     } else { //if not checked
         $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_FinishDateSrvcTXT').val('');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

```
$('#<%=FinishFillCHK.ClientID%>')
```

it may not make any difference in whats happening for you but is a much better way to get the ID of a control.